# How to install OfficeJS Addin on sharepoint

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-js, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-2016

I have written a small officeJS addin for excel which run perfectly on desktop excel client. Also office online gives an option of installing the addin from the ribbon menu. I want to do the same for microsoft sharepoint server 2016 which can be maintained centrally by an administrator. [The addins options is available in office online, but not available through sharepoint, PFA image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByYbE.png)

Comment: I've alerted the SharePoint product team to your question. Perhaps the version of Excel Online in your version of SharePoint Server doesn't support add-ins.

Comment: @RickKirkham I am also wondering on how to install the addin on office online server? Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: @RickKirkham I am planning to use office online server for hosting excel worksheets, is there a way to directly install the addin on office online server?

Comment: This is really a different question. You'll get more attention to it if you create a new StackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. On a server in the farm, open the **SharePoint Management Shell** (PowerShell). Run this command:

```
Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm - OfficeAddinEnabled:$true
```

You probably have to be logged in as a farm administrator.
There is some documentation here: [Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219442(v=office.16).aspx)

Comment: can you answer this question?  [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/964685/how-to-enable-office-add-ins-on-documents-served-via-on-premise-office-online-se)

Comment: Answered at the link.